# Xdebug not working for PHP on MAMP

Tags: php, mamp, xdebug

I am trying to install Xdebug for NetBeans. I am using a MAC and coding in PHP. I can see that xdebug.so is present at

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.2/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/xdebug.so
```

The php.ini settings are:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.2/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/xdebug.so"
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
```

The NetBeans is listening at port 9000 too. But every time I launch the debugger it says Waiting for Connection (netbeans-debug)

The `phpinfo()` has no mention of xdebug ... why is this in spite of xdebug.so being present?

How do I make this work?

Comment: 1) Have you restarted your web server after making these changes? 2) Double check that you have edited the right php.ini. You can check `phpinfo()` output to see what config files were used (it's in top header table). It's quite possible that you have one php.ini used fro CLI and one for Apache .. and you may have edited the wrong one.

Comment: you were right... I was looking at the wrong php.ini